# Is there a way to export multiple dataframes into one excel file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple data frames created in pandas and I want to export the output of each of those data frames into separate tabs within the same excel file.

I know how to export each data frame to its own csv, but how can I get the output from each data frame into one excel file?

Have only tried to export the data to separate csv files

```
df1 = data.query('total_1 > 0').pivot_table(index='name',
           columns='month',
           values='conv',
           aggfunc='sum',
           margins=True,
           margins_name='Total'
          ).style.format("{:,.0f}")

df1.to_csv(DESKTOP_PATH + 'df1.csv')


df2 = data.query('total_2 > 0').pivot_table(index='name',
           columns='month',
           values='conv',
           aggfunc='sum',
           margins=True,
           margins_name='Total'
          ).style.format("{:,.0f}")

df2.to_csv(DESKTOP_PATH + 'df2.csv')
```

Would like to write to just one excel file instead of a csv file and include the output of both df1 and df2 in separate tabs of the same excel file

Comment: Have you tried to use to_xlxs?

Comment: Sure, I can use _xlxs but still need to figure out how to export the contents of both data frames into one excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pd.ExcelWriter` together with `to_excel` within the manager context `with`

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('c:\\test.xls') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```