# Python DataFrame - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Python 3.8

I'm fairly new to Python, and I need to deliver this project before Friday 11/12/20.
I have a DataFrame and I have to print both the mean and the standard deviation of the 'price' key for the columns saved in name_list.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
#Grouping by company, fuel type, aspiration, door number
#Creating an empty DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame()
#Saving all the prices
values = df['price'].unique()
name_list = ['CarName', 'fueltype', 'aspiration', 'doornumber']
#Cycling for each column and saving the mean and standard deviation in the empty dataframe
for name, value in name_list, values:
    result["Mean Price = ", value] = df[df.price == value][name].mean()
    result["Standard Deviation = ", value] = df[df.price == value][name].std()

#result = result.dropna()

#Saving mean price and standard deviation to a csv file
result.to_csv("MeanPrice_StdDeviation.csv", index=False)
```

When I run the code, I get the error:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I read online you could use the items method, but it doesn't work as I get this error if I do try that:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'

How do I solve this?

EDIT:
This is the full error message I get if I try the nested for loop.
Lines of this part of my code are from 38 to 53.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1303, in _ensure_numeric
    x = float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'alfa-romero giulia'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1307, in _ensure_numeric
    x = complex(x)

ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\mazza\documents\informatica\progetto_esame_peruzzini_mazzanti.py", line 48, in <module>
    result["Mean Price = ", value] = df[df.price == value][name].mean()

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11214, in stat_func
    return self._reduce(

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3891, in _reduce
    return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 69, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 125, in f
    result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 542, in nanmean
    the_sum = _ensure_numeric(values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum))

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1310, in _ensure_numeric
    raise TypeError(f"Could not convert {x} to numeric")

TypeError: Could not convert alfa-romero giulia to numeric


debugfile('C:/Users/mazza/Documents/Informatica/progetto_esame_peruzzini_mazzanti.py', wdir='C:/Users/mazza/Documents/Informatica')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1303, in _ensure_numeric
    x = float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'alfa-romero giulia'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1307, in _ensure_numeric
    x = complex(x)

ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\mazza\documents\informatica\progetto_esame_peruzzini_mazzanti.py", line 47, in <module>
    result["Mean Price = ", value] = df[df.price == value][name].mean()

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11214, in stat_func
    return self._reduce(

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3891, in _reduce
    return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 69, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 125, in f
    result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 542, in nanmean
    the_sum = _ensure_numeric(values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum))

  File "C:\Users\mazza\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1310, in _ensure_numeric
    raise TypeError(f"Could not convert {x} to numeric")

TypeError: Could not convert alfa-romero giulia to numeric
```

Comment: This is because of unmatched length of your  name_list and values in loop. Try to use Nested for loop if you have unmatched length of lists/arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this issue because `name_list` and `values` are of unequal length. Try the below code by using two `for` loops (nested):

```
#Grouping by company, fuel type, aspiration, door number
#Creating an empty DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame()
#Saving all the prices
values = df['price'].unique()
name_list = ['CarName', 'fueltype', 'aspiration', 'doornumber']
#Cycling for each column and saving the mean and standard deviation in the empty dataframe   
for name in name_list:
    for value in values:
        result["Mean Price = ", value] = df[df.price == value][name].mean()
        result["Standard Deviation = ", value] = df[df.price == value][name].std()

#result = result.dropna()

#Saving mean price and standard deviation to a csv file
result.to_csv("MeanPrice_StdDeviation.csv", index=False)
```

Edit following OP's comments:

```
#Grouping by company, fuel type, aspiration, door number
#Creating an empty DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame()
#Saving all the prices
values = df['price'].unique()
name_list = ['CarName', 'fueltype', 'aspiration', 'doornumber']
#Cycling for each column and saving the mean and standard deviation in the empty dataframe   
for column in name_list:    
    print(df.groupby([column])['price'].mean().reset_index())
    print(df.groupby([column])['price'].std().reset_index())
```

Comment: @Mazza which error? please paste it here in comments.

Comment: TypeError: Could not convert alfa-romero giulia to numeric

Comment: @Mazza This means the code expects a numeric value instead of the string `alfa-romeo`. In which exact line are you getting this error?

Comment: tried debugging and it happens on the first iteration of: result["Mean Price = ", value] = df[df.price == value][name].mean()

Comment: @Mazza Ok now I understand your problem, the logic for getting mean is wrong as [name] is a non-numeric value. I have updated the answer to get mean and standard deviation by grouping on each of the columns mentioned. Do mark the answer as correct if this solves your problem.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but that doesn't save the file as csv right? how do I do that part? the way you suggested appears to be working in the console

Comment: Sir/Mam, I think you have got the answer for your original question and a subsequent question as well. Please raise a separate query for this question as saving data into csv with different headers is a different challenge. Meanwhile request you to mark this one as correct answer if you are getting the correct output values.

Comment: Actually your code had many logical errors so after resolving those, the scenario has changed. It would be better if you give csv part a try yourself and if face issues then reach out to the community rather than asking for step wise instructions. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897821/is-there-a-way-to-export-multiple-dataframes-into-one-excel-file

Comment: in my defense I had already written a similar code to the suggested one, but have close to no clue on how to save a csv file from that result

Comment: @Mazza no worries, give it a little try, let me know if you were able to solve the csv part else i'll help you sort it out.. :)